# Transforming a form to a read-only layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create the layout for a profile page.

When the user is editing his profile, I want to display a form such as this one from the Bootstrap library: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#form-row . When the user is done editing, I want to convert the form to a read-only layout, by replacing the input fields with the text that has been entered.

I found an example on bootsnipp: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/QoM7g (tab "Education&Career", for example). But when looking at the code, I noticed that this layout was constructed using the  form-group class, and by replacing the input field with a paragraph field.

Is there a cleaner solution? I can't imagine this is how this kind of layout is meant to be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have  elements in your form styled as plain text, use the .form-control-plaintext class to remove the default form field styling and preserve the correct margin and padding.

for Example:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Refer to this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

Add a fieldset with disabled attribute, all form element will be disabled.

Now add style to default `form-control` elements so that it will look like text.

Example below

```css
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  color:red;
  border: none;
  background-color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-3">
  <form>
    <fieldset disabled>
      <input class="form-control" type='text' value='John' />
      <input class="form-control" type='text' value='John' />
      <input class="form-control" type='text' value='John' />
      <input class="form-control" type='text' value='John' />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to replace the fields. You can just style them to look as text: hide the border and outline, make it read-only, make the background same as the outer background.

Example:

```html
    <input value="Regular input" />
    <br>
    <input class="like-text" value="I look like a text" readonly />
```

```css
    .like-text {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z879pbcn/